# How to select only entries that didn't repeat before a specific date?

Tags: mysql, sql

My issue is that I'm stuck on making a select query where I need to select only items from latest 24 hours, that don't repeat themselves on entries before those 24 hours.

Here is a table:

| name | date |
| --- | --- |
| Mark | 2021-05-27 |
| Jake | 2021-05-27 |
| Anthony | 2021-05-27 |
| Anthony | 2021-05-26 |

Expected output:

| name |
| --- |
| Mark |
| Jake |

Missing element: **query**

Help will be appreciated.

Edit: I know that's unprecise. The real table I'm using is with full datetime type. I'm going to test your answers today and then give response.

Comment: In your example data, there is no way to check for 24 hours, as you have only dates. I assume you mean *before 1 day*. But then, your example is not correct, because the first entry for `Anthony` has a date *exactly* 1 day before the second, which technically would not qualify as being *before* 1 day earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*'24 hours'* is unprecise, as you do not know which dates of yesterday are actually in range of the past 24 hours. If you are ok only with today's entries only (which are less), then the following would work:

```
SELECT name FROM demoTable GROUP BY name HAVING MIN(date) = CURRENT_DATE;
```

If you actually have date *and* time available, then you can have:

```
SELECT name FROM demoTable
    GROUP BY name HAVING MIN(datetime) > DATEADD(day, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Depending on SQL dialect, `DATEADD(...)` might not be available, with e. g. SQLite you'd replace it by `DATETIME('now', '-1 day')`.

Comment: Works as intended, thank you. This query just makes my brain steaming when trying to understand it. So GROUP BY just groups names into groups of specific names that have their own counting value. What exactly happens in the HAVING part?

Comment: @Iqaru `HAVING` is for groups what is `WHERE` for non-grouped statements: Conditions that are evaluated per group.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand. Some messing with the select queries helped me. So a `MIN(date)` just returns the minimum date value for specific group of names, and if it happened to be not less than latest 24 hours, it gets returned in a result. I've got a lot to learn. Thanks a lot

Comment: In `less` I meant `later`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.name
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.`date` = CURRENT_DATE
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM tablename t2
                   WHERE t1.name = t2.name
                     AND t2.`date` < CURRENT_DATE );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below query to get the last 24 data without duplicate name

```
select name from tabl1 where date>getdate()-1 group by name having count(name)>0
```

Here `getdate()-1` will give the last 1 day difference i.e. `24hr`

Comment: This will include 'Anthony' as there is an entry with appropriate date. `HAVING COUNT(name) > 0)` is obsolete as groups with zero count are not listed anyway/do not even exist.